# summernote: how to limit file size?

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am using the summernote jquery plugin

I am trying to limit the size of the data image (ex: 30 Kbytes)

```
                callbacks: {
                        onImageUpload: function(files, editor, $editable) {
                            if (files[0].size>30000) {
                                alert('Size too big')
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                // What to do to insert the file into the summer editor ?
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Can't you just return true; ?

Comment: I did: nothing.
But I found the solution: there is a paramater max_size !

Comment: your code is working i did use in my project and seems fine.